# SELECT with COUNT, GROUP BY, ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm back with another mysql query question. This time, given a time range, I need to select the date of the last order of a customer AND the total number of order that customer placed within  that time range.

The (stripped) query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
   customers_id, 
   customers_name, 
   date_purchased, 
   count(*) as total_order 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY customers_id;
```

Obviously the date_purchased returned there is not of the LAST order of the customer within the time range, but I can't order before group by, is there anyway to get around this? For example should I order first, then group by (nested selects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select customers_id,
       customers_name,
       MAX(date_purchased) as last_purchase,
       count(*) as total_order
from orders
group by customers_id,customers_name;
```

Comment: What's the point of adding `customers_name` to GROUP fields? ID is obviously more unique.

Comment: Could be 'cause I'm coming from a SQL Server rather than MySQL background - MSSQL requires all fields to be specified in the GROUP BY if they're not aggregated - I'm guessing MySQL doesn't?

Comment: I see. Sorry then. Yes, MySQL doesn't require all unaggregated fields in GROUP BY, and just puts the last value it sees.

Comment: No problem - you're totally right, I needn't have grouped by the field then - I prefer to group by such fields (and have to with T-SQL in MSSQL) - whilst it is 'not needed' I don't think it necessarily hurts performance _all that much_.  :)

Answer (score 2):

`MAX(date_purchased)` if it's a DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP column. If it's string, you'll need to convert it like `MAX(STR_TO_DATE(date_purchased, '%m-%d-%Y'))` or whatever your format is.

And regarding date range... Add a `WHERE date_purchased BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-02-04'` or whatever your range is. If start/end date aren't in this format you'll need to use `STR_TO_DATE` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customers_id,
       customers_name,
       MAX(date_purchased) as most_current_purchase_within_range,
       count(*) as total_amount_of_orders
from orders
where (date_purchased between ('2011-01-01') and ('2011-12-31'))
group by customers_id
```